# Installing and running applications remotely

Tags: remote, home-server

I was wondering if it was possible to run applications on a local machine from a remote server.

Example:

Desktop1 executes program from Server. The program then is loaded from the Server and runs on Desktop1.

I have a few desktops and it would be easier to manage and save disk space to have applications remotely.

Would this work on Windows or possible Linux?

Comment: Yes through Remote Desktop

Comment: Your application would have to support client/server technology, otherwise you need to use RDP (ie... Remote Desktop Services/TerminalServer) or use another remote access application...

Answer (score 2):

"Desktop1 executes program from Server. The program then is loaded from the Server and runs on Desktop1."

If what's written above is what you actually want, then simply share the folder/directory the program resides in (on the server) and then access that share from the desktop and run the program.

It will load off the server's drives (over the network) into the desktop's memory and run.

This is a standard capability of any modern, network-enabled OS.

Answer (score 0):

[SSH (Secure Shell)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH) is a cryptographic network protocol for secure data communication, remote command-line login, remote command execution, and other secure network services between two networked computers that connects, via a secure channel over an insecure network, a server and a client.SSH can be used to login to a remote computer given , a SSH daemon is running on the remote system. It was designed as a replacement for Telnet and other insecure remote shell protocols.In linux , SSH is built into it.So , inorder to access the remote shell you can use an SSH utility.You can enable X11 forwarding features to see the desktop of the remote server.A good start to SSH will be [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HBOM7Zq61E).You can always find good guides on setting up SSH server over internet.

If you just want to connect via SSH you need to install a ssh daemon for windows.I would suggest you [OpenSSH for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshwindows/).Unix emulator like [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) must be installed to get the Open SSH suite installed on your Windows machine.But this way you can only run shell commands in the remote server.i.e,You may not be able to interact with GUI this way , since there is no X windows forwarding in windows.
Inorder to forward the graphical environment from remote server you may have to use remote desktop applications like [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/),[Team viewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Web applications are designed to do exactly that.
If you want to use your server as remote terminal, then need to use a variation of remote desktop/access